# How to fix errors for threadpool executor

Tags: python, threadpool

I wrote the following function. Because there are so many keywords, I try to use Threadpool

```
class AllFind():

    def __init__(
            self
            ):
            self._session = Session()


    def find_kewword(
            self,
            keyword,
            ):
            url = "https://xxxxxxxx.yy"
            params = {
            "keyword" : keyword,
            "version" : 5,
            }
            res = self._session.get(url, params=params)
            res_count = res.json().get("count")
            return res_count
```

I tried this code but it failed. In this way, only the result value for the end of the keyword_list is displayed. What is wrong?

```
obj = AllFind()
keyword_list = [1,23,4,5,6.....]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        task = executor.submit(obj.find_keyword, keyword_list)
```

Comment: if you want to run `find_keyword` for every keyword separatelly then you should use `map()` instead of `submit()`

Comment: your code runs `find_keyword` only once with `"keyword" : keyword_list` and I don't know why you need `Threadpool` for this.